# Azure-cosmos: To fetch the document from container based on the key which contains an array of strings. Need help for non-strict comparsion

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

ARRAY_CONTAINS function check for the strict comparison from an array of strings. Do we  have any method that makes non-strict comparison for an array of strings from a given input string.

Example: We have a document in container like this

> {
> "id":1,
> "category":["cosmos","mongo"]
> }

But , if we are fetching for documents like
`SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(u.category,('Mongo'))`

The above query returns null as it was checking for the strict comparison .Do we have any function for non-strict comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringEquals`. It can do a case-insensitive comparison and is still able to leverage the index.

```sql
SELECT c.id
FROM c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM c 
    JOIN category IN c.category 
    WHERE StringEquals(category, 'Cosmos', true)
    )
```

Comment: Just note that this solution uses an index scan, and is not as efficient as passing in a lower-case version of the search string, knowing that the stored property is in lower-case.

Comment: @DavidMakogon good point. It's an expanded index scan though, which is still quite efficient compared to other functions to achieve similar results like `LOWER(<exp>)`.